# Plotting with Vennerable package in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

Here is a very basic example:

```
library(vennerable)    
srl.venn <- Venn(SetNames=c("Cognitive condition","Operations","Individual differences"),
                 Weight=c(0,30, 21, 15, 1, 8, 3, 6))
plot(srl.venn)
```

All I'm trying to do is to remove borders around circles, and format colors and fonts. However, still haven't done much.

Could you please share any useful examples?

Comment: Hi gung, if you run this, it should produce a diagram...

Comment: library loading and plot, but that's it. It's a simple diagram, I just need an example how to format colors and fonts.

Comment: My apologies, I don't know the package, I didn't realize that was a reproducible example. In that case, this should be migratable to [SO], where this Q should be on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `VennThemes` for changing parameters within the plot. For example:

```
library(Vennerable)

    srl.venn <- Venn(SetNames=c("Cognitive condition","Operations","Individual differences"),
                     Weight=c(0,30, 21, 15, 1, 8, 3, 6))

    srl.venn.c <- compute.Venn(srl.venn, doWeights=T)
    gp <- VennThemes(srl.venn.c, colourAlgorithm = "binary")

    plot(srl.venn.c, gpList = gp, show = list(FaceText = "signature", SetLabels = FALSE,
                         Faces = FALSE,  DarkMatter = FALSE))
```

[image]

More detail can be found in the man pages or by calling `vignette("Venn")`

Comment: Thanks Stedy! I tried that, but obviously got something wrong. Anyways, will read again.